# Good tutorials for the awe6 game framework?

Tags: frameworks, haxe

Just recently I stumbled upon the [awe6 game framework](http://code.google.com/p/awe6/) for Haxe and I want to give it a try, but the only "tutorial" on the site is a prebuilt FlashDevelop project template that also appears to be quite complex already.

I've tried to dissect the template but some things are quite weird and I can't figure out why the template seems to work, so I'd rather prefer a tutorial (or at least a very simple "Hello World" example) that sets everything up and runs without assuming a specific IDE. I've also tried Google but almost all of the results were leading back to the FlashDevelop template.

Are there any tutorials/examples/simple demos with source code for awe6 that are not burried in a IDE specific template and are step-by-step and/or otherwise easy to understand?

Comment: I would also like to see some more examples, even if its just integration with another simple framework to create spaceinvaders or something. awe6 looks amazing but has a huge learning curve for people who make casual browser based games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are working on a suite of tutorials (and videos).  In the meanwhile please see this very simple Hello World example which leads on to the templates (now also available as Linux bash scripts):

http://code.google.com/p/awe6/wiki/ExampleHelloWorld

Comment: 2+ years later: still just a hello world example...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer, but the framework's author [Rob Fell](https://twitter.com/hypersurge) did a presentation a few weeks ago at the WWX conference:

- [slides](https://prezi.com/yzvwdmevm9_c/p-may-the-force-be-with-you-making-a-game-with-awe6/?auth_key=8eadceff59596f8a8b289c119c02fa3dc670c4b9)
- [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH2inmm_qYc)

Answer (score 1):

Valerie Elimak's presentation has a couple of good examples http://workshops.elimak.com/awe6june12/